# %1 is not a valid Win32 application ERROR WITH HANA

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, hana

This error occurs when trying to connect HANA with Visual Studio.
I have tried with SAP 32-bit client and 64-bit client. but there was no different.
Any suggestions?

> ex. InnerException: {"%1 is not a valid Win32 application"}
> ex.Message: The type initializer for 'Sap.Data.Hana.HanaConnection' threw an exception.
> ex.Source: "Sap.Data.Hana.v4.5"

[image: screenshot]

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include source code formatted instead of images. 
Please check the documentation [on how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this,  install hdbclient 32 bit and copy libadonetHDB32.dll/.pdb again as libadonetHDB.dll/ pdb into hdbclient.